# Remove all objects from environment except those matching a given pattern

Tags: r

I'm trying to remove all **objects** from my RStudio **environment** where the object names are NOT equal to a pattern.

```
rm(list=ls(pattern!="may19"))
```

However this gives me an error

> Error in as.environment(pos) :    no item called "pattern != "may19""
>   on the search list

Is there another way to approach this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe regular expressions might help here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use one of the following(other variants might exist, you can add `all=TRUE` or `all.names=TRUE`) for completeness:

```
rm(list=setdiff(ls(),"may19"))
rm(list=ls(pattern = "[^may19]"))
```

Comment: I'd like to remove objects where the object name is NOT equal to the pattern. I think your code suggests the opposite?

Comment: That's a different question. I think your comment is on the wrong question. Columns and `object names ` are two different things. Compare this with your new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56703646/r-drop-columns-from-dataframe-if-column-names-feature-in-vector These are two very different things.

Comment: Sorry I edited my comment above. How could I adapt your code to remove objects from my R environment where the pattern is not equal to "may19"?

Comment: This is what the code does. Is this not what you want? Not exactly sure what you need. Try running this code in a fresh R session and only include two **objects** named may19 and may20 then see what it does.

Comment: I tried, but it deletes objects whose names contain the mention 'may19'.

Comment: You need to ask a new question. What you want to do us completely different from what you asked. You need to look through all objects and their names then delete. This is a different question.

Comment: New question created. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56704121/remove-all-objects-from-r-environment-whose-names-do-not-contain-a-string

Comment: If this answer helped you to solve your issue, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

@Varun, NelsonGon's solution didn't work for me either. Try this instead (a combination of his two suggested lines):

```
rm(list = setdiff(ls(), ls(pattern = "may19"))
```

That should remove all objects from workspace except those with "may19".