# Remove all objects from R environment whose names DO NOT contain a specific string

Tags: r

I'd like to remove all objects from my RStudio environment where the object names DO NOT contain a given string.

```
rm(list=ls(pattern!="may19"))
```

Yet this gives me an error message

> Error in as.environment(pos) : no item called "pattern != "may19"" on
>   the search list

Is there another way I can approach this? Thanks

Comment: How is this different from your earlier question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56702965/remove-all-objects-from-environment-except-those-matching-a-given-pattern

Comment: @RonakShah In that question, OP wanted to find **objects** that match a name before changing their mind an hour later. I then advised that they create a new question since these were two different issues.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
rm(list= names(Filter(function(x) !any(names(x) == "may19"),
       mget(ls(),envir = .GlobalEnv))))
```

Or simply(as suggested by @nicola):

```
rm(list=grep("may19",ls(),value=TRUE,invert=TRUE))
```

Comment: Please include the packages you are using or, still better, try to use external packages only if really needed.

Comment: Thank you. On running this code, I get the following error - Error in attr(data, "tsp") <- c(start, end, frequency) : 
  object is not a matrix

Comment: @nicola I'm only using `base`.

Comment: @NelsonGon `%>%` is not a base operator.

Comment: @nicola Oh, sorry. It's just that I'm so used to the `tidyverse` that I sometimes forget.

Comment: @Varun It's hard for me to know what's going on. Could you convert it to a matrix?

Comment: Maybe simpler: `rm(list=grep("may19",ls(),value=TRUE,invert=TRUE))`.

Comment: Thanks @nicola That's a really simple option.

Comment: Even much simpler `rm(list = ls()[!grepl("may19", ls())])`